# Forget adsense code while activating account

Tags: google-adsense

What I have done is:

1. Created adsense account
2. Created an ad unit
3. Placed that ad unit code on my website
4. After few days I removed that adsense code from my website
5. Now when I open my adsense account the following page is displayed: 
   [image]

   And when I again submit request for account approval, I receive email with status:

> Site does not comply with Google policies

And in recommendations:

```
Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
```

Now my question is:

Is Google evaluting my website on the basis of adsense code? If yes how can I get the code again? or what is its alternative? How can I delete this account and create a new one?

**Update:**

I can neither go to `My Ads` tab nor delete my account. The only page displayed is shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The webpages where you included the Adsense code did not comply Adsense's policy. If you create another account to get a code to use in the same pages, then the same will happen. You need to modify your website in order to make it possible to use Adsense.

Make sure the website is not [is not violating AdSense policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688?hl=en) and then [Report or appeal a policy violation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1205533?hl=en).

Comment: I don't need another code or another account. There is no adsense code placed on my website right now, as I deleted it myself. How can I get that code again!

Comment: Just visit the `My ads` tab, it will display a list of your ads and they have the code inside.

Comment: As mentioned in question I can neither go to `My Ads` tab nor delete my account. The only page displayed is shown in question(screen shot)

Comment: If you don't have any adsense code in any site and you don't have any other adsense account, just reapply to be able to access again.

Comment: How can I reapply? There is no such option on this page

Answer (score 0):

[Google adsense makes process faster for publisher](https://adsense.googleblog.com/2015/10/signing-up-for-adsense-is-now-faster.html). So when you apply for adsense ads they will allowed to place their ads on your website without reviewing your actual website.

You have succesfully place the adsense code and later you have remove it. and on that time your application was not under review, and once they reviewed it, they find out you're not qualified for their adsense program, hence you can't do other things now. You can get those adsense code on early days when your account was still on pending, but now they have renew it, and deny your application, so now you can't access to your account.

Improve your content, and reaply for adsense again.